# Find Git version with --allow-unrelated-histories

Tags: git

I have a script that uses `git pull --allow-unrelated-histories` and I want to provide a version requirements list.

I know that Git 1.7.1 does not allow unrelated histories, and I know that Git 2.15.1 does (since I'm running that).

How do I find out the minimum Git version a user needs in order to run the script?

Answer (score 3):

You asked *how to find it* rather than *what is it*, and the answer to that is to look through the [Git release notes](https://github.com/git/git/tree/master/Documentation/RelNotes).  In general, big changes—like adding the flag, and requiring it, rather than simply *assuming* that the merge should merge unrelated histories—get a release-notes entry.

(In this case you'll find it in [the 2.9.0 release notes](https://github.com/git/git/blob/master/Documentation/RelNotes/2.9.0.txt).)

(Also in general, it's a lot faster to clone the Git repository for Git, then search this Git repository, than it is to poke through individual files using the GitHub web interface links above.)